# Harmon.ie with Outlook: error message Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Synchronization

Tags: sharepoint-2010, outlook-2013, harmon.ie

I installed Harmon.ie for Outlook and I configured my SharePoint 2010 site with it.
When I want to access in the document folder, I get the following error message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Synchronization, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error is returned by SharePoint web service. Try running Microsoft Sync Framework repair or re-install (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15391) on the server